# Criar variavel angular no html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, variáveis, ng-repeat

Olá!

Eu tenho um loop (ng-repeat) no meu arquivo html e gostaria de salvar o index dela em uma variável para poder passar por parâmetro para uma função.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Segue o código na View:

```
<div class="lista_cores">
    <div class="opcao_tamanho col-xs-12" ng-repeat="tamanho in vm.tamanho">
    {{vm.index = $index}}
        <div class="lista_cores" ng-repeat="cor in tamanho.cor track by $index">
            <button type="button" class="btn_remove" ng-click="vm.removeCor(vm.index, $index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn_adiciona" ng-click="vm.addCor($index)">Adicionar cor</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn_remove" ng-click="vm.removeTamanho($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn_adiciona" ng-click="vm.addTamanho($index)">Adicionar tamanho</button>
```

Função no Controller:

```
vm.tamanho = [{
        "nome_produto_tamanho": "",
        "cor": [{
            "nome_produto_cor": ""
        }]
    }];
    vm.addTamanho = function(index){
        vm.tamanho.push({
            "nome_produto_tamanho": "",
            "cor": [{
                "nome_produto_cor": ""
            }]
        });
    }
    vm.removeTamanho = function(index) {
        vm.tamanho.splice(index, 1);
    };

    vm.cores = {
        "nome_produto_cor": ""
    };
    vm.addCor = function(id_tamanho){
        vm.tamanho[id_tamanho].cor.push(vm.cores);
    }
    vm.removeCor = function(id_tamanho, index) {
        console.log(index);
        console.log(id_tamanho);
        vm.tamanho[id_tamanho].cor.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

O código foi bastante simplificado, porém é basicamente essa a parte que importa.

O usuário pode adicionar cor e tamanho clicando em um botão e remover também, o meu problema é ao remover uma cor adicionada, pois necessito do id do tamanho para poder então apagar a cor.

Comment: poderia [edit] sua pergunta e adicionar como está seu código atual?

Comment: @David, inseri o meu código

Comment: Pergunta - porque não passar o objeto completo como parâmetro?

Comment: pois eu n tenho um id dentro do objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma: eu coloquei uma div com `display: none` e criei uma uma variavel vazia dentro do json, chamada `"id_Array"`, que eu preencho da seguinte forma: `{{tamanho.id_array = $index}}`, logo abaixo do primeiro ng-repeat, daí como esse código fica dentro do display none, ele não irá aparecer na tela.